# Can't use JSON Extractor or jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion to confirm a value in a response

Tags: json, jmeter

I cant seem to confirm if a user was assigned a role.  I've tried using the JSON Extractor element and the jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion element.  Either way, it does not seem to be able to grab the true or false value.  I've been using my handy helper tool, http://jsonpath.com/ to locate the correct JSON path.  In both the extractor and the assertion, I have a JSON path =

```
$.[?(@.productDisplayName=='User Access')].[?(@.name=='CUSTOMER_ADMIN')].assigned
```

I'm expecting to get the value = true but for some odd reason, this response is not letting me confirm that value.  The response I get for the JSON Path Assertion is:

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Value expected to be 'true', but found '[]'
```

If I attempt the JSON Extraction, the variable never seems to get a value, not even [true]!

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the response:

```
{
  "@rpc": "1.0",
  "@types": [
    "com.test.blah.user.ProductRoleSecurity",
    "com.test.blah.user.ProductRoleCategory",
    "com.test.blah.user.ProductRoleAssignment"
  ],
  "@data": [
    {
      "@type": 0,
      "productRoleCategories": [
        {
          "@type": 1,
          "categoryDescriptionLocaleKey": "blah.product.label.category.default.description",
          "categoryDisplayName": "Default",
          "categoryKey": "default",
          "categoryDisplayLocaleKey": "blah.product.label.category.default.displayName",
          "roleAssignments": [
            {
              "@type": 2,
              "displayName": "Customer Administrator",
              "requiredAttributes": [],
              "name": "CUSTOMER_ADMIN",
              "description": "Standard customer administrator role",
              "assigned": true,
              "roleCategoryString": "CUSTOMER_ADMIN:na:assigned=true"
            },
            {
              "@type": 2,
              "displayName": "U.P. Test",
              "requiredAttributes": [],
              "name": "UP-TEST",
              "description": "Test for user provisionable",
              "assigned": false,
              "roleCategoryString": "UP-TEST:na:assigned=false"
            }
          ],
          "categoryDescription": "Default"
        }
      ],
      "productDisplayName": "User Access",
      "productName": "UA",
      "productDescription": "User Access"
    },
    {
      "@type": 0,
      "productRoleCategories": [
        {
          "@type": 1,
          "categoryDescriptionLocaleKey": "blah.product.label.category.default.description",
          "categoryDisplayName": "Default",
          "categoryKey": "default",
          "categoryDisplayLocaleKey": "blah.product.label.category.default.displayName",
          "roleAssignments": [
            {
              "@type": 2,
              "displayName": "User",
              "requiredAttributes": [],
              "name": "USER",
              "description": "Other product User role",
              "assigned": true,
              "roleCategoryString": "USER:na:assigned=true"
            },
            {
              "@type": 2,
              "displayName": "Super User",
              "requiredAttributes": [],
              "name": "SUPER_USER",
              "description": "Super User role",
              "assigned": false,
              "roleCategoryString": "SUPER_USER:na:assigned=false"
            }
          ],
          "categoryDescription": "Default"
        }
      ],
      "productDisplayName": "Other Product",
      "productName": "SDR",
      "productDescription": "Other Product"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON Path query doesn't match anything (both parts), moreover, you are trying to combine 2 clauses in weird manner.

You need to amend it to something like:

```
$..[?(@.productDisplayName=='User Access' && @.productRoleCategories[0].roleAssignments[0].name=='CUSTOMER_ADMIN')].productRoleCategories[0].roleAssignments[0].assigned
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JsonPath multiple clauses]

References:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: I came up with this `$.@data.[?(@.productDisplayName=='User Access')].productRoleCategories[0].roleAssignments[?(@.name=='CUSTOMER_ADMIN')].assigned` but your solution is much better.  Thank you again Dmitri!  Also, i used jmeter's JSON Path tester to help me get as far as I did.  It's a nice tool.